# Is there a way to dynamically create a board this way w/ an unknown size?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a version of the NQueens problem and the size of the board is read from a file. I've only been able to make a 4x4 board work.

```
  int board[N][N] =     { {0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0} };
```

Is there a way to dynamically create a board this way w/ an unknown size?

Comment: With a `std::vector`? Just allocate `N*N` elements.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> board(Ysize, std::vector<int>(Xsize));` but a more effective version would allocate a 1D vector and address it as a 2D vector.

Comment: FYI: you can just write {{0}} or possible {} (not sure) and all the rest are 0 by default

Comment: `int board[N][N]{};` would be enough to zero-initialize it.

Answer (score 3):

The container provided in the standard library to handle dynamically allocating arrays is `std::vector`

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> board(N, std::vector<int>(N));
```

Or if you prefer you can allocate a 1D array and use array striding

```
std::vector<int> board(N*N);
```

Comment: Thank you! So adding 0's in the curly braces is unnecessary?

Comment: It's unnecessary for a vector.